# Is it possible to set argparse's optional argument to a default value based on other optional argument?

Tags: python, argparse

I am using `argparse` and I have two optional arguments:

```
  parser.add_argument('-a', '--arg1', default=1, type=int)
  parser.add_argument('-b', '--arg2', action='store_true', default=False)
```

Is there a way to set `arg1` default value of "1" if only if `arg2` is set `True`?

In other word, I only want to do the following only if `arg2` is set to `True`:

```
  parser.add_argument('-a', '--arg1', default=1, type=int)
```

Otherwise, it will be set to:

```
  parser.add_argument('-a', '--arg1', type=int)
```

Answer (score 2):

A test after parsing would be the simplest way to achieve this:

```
if args.arg2 and args.arg1 is None:
    args.arg1 = 1
```

You could put this sort of test in an custom Action.  You have to take into consideration the order of occurance (or not).  I haven't worked out the details, but I can't imagine it being any simpler than this post-parse test.