# Parsing exclusive groups in Python

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

I have 2 group which are exclusive, you can define either arguments from `group1` or `group2` but `group2` have to be exclusive within it's arguments too.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
group_exclusive = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
sub_exclusive_1 = group_exclusive.add_argument_group()
sub_exclusive_1.add_argument("-a")
sub_exclusive_1.add_argument("-b")
sub_exclusive_1.add_argument("-c")
sub_exclusive_1.add_argument("-d")

sub_exclusive_2 = group_exclusive.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
sub_exclusive_2.add_argument("-AA")
sub_exclusive_2.add_argument("-BB")

args = parser.parse_args()
```

The code have to terminate if `[-a and -AA or -BB]` or `[-AA and -BB]` have been defined but still have to work with [`-a` and/or `-b`],

The problem is that it's not terminating...

I found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17909294/python-argparse-mutual-exclusive-group) and edited my code to

```
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
parser_a = subparsers.add_parser('command_1')
parser_a.add_argument("-a")
parser_a.add_argument("-b")
parser_a.add_argument("-c")
parser_a.add_argument("-d")

parser_b = subparsers.add_parser('command_2')
parser_b.add_argument("-AA")
parser_b.add_argument("-BB")
```

still does not work, traceback: `main.py: error: too few arguments`

What do i do wrong?

current workaround:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-a")
...
parser.add_argument("-AA")

args = parser.parse_args()
if (args.a or args.b or args.c or args.d) and (args.AA or args.BB) or (args.AA and args.BB):
    raise SystemExit()
```

Comment: why don't you create another mutually exclusive group inside `exclusive_2`?

Comment: @n9code to make `-AA` and `-BB` exclusive to eachother, only one of them can be defined

Comment: so what is the problem? In your first snippet you could do `sub_sub_2 = sub_exclusive_2.add_mutually_exclusive_group()`, and then add your `-AA` and `-BB` into that group. Thus they will be must-exclusive. BTW you have a bug in your code - suggested an edit.

Comment: @n9code thx for noticing the bug, as i said, the code does not terminate when passing `-a` and `-AA` to it... thats the main issue

Comment: ok I got it. let me think

Comment: should it work with no arguments?

Comment: @n9code yeap it should

Comment: then the solution with `sub_commands` will not work :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the risk of repeating my answer from the earlier question, let's focus on your case

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
group_exclusive = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
sub_exclusive_1 = group_exclusive.add_argument_group()
...

sub_exclusive_2 = group_exclusive.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
sub_exclusive_2.add_argument("-AA")
sub_exclusive_2.add_argument("-BB")
```

Despite similar names (and class nesting), the functionality of argument_groups and mutually_exclusive_groups is quite different.  And the former does not nest meaningfully within the second.

An argument group is a tool to organize arguments in the help.  It does not enter arguments 'as a group' into another group, and has NO effect on parsing or error checking.

If it did act as you want, what would the `usage` line look like?

With the subparser formulation the parser responds with:

```
prog command1 -a -b -c  # ok
prog command1 -a -AA    # error - not recognize -AA
prog command2 -AA -BB   # ok
prog command2 -a -AA    # error - -a not recognized
prog -AA                # error - too few arg
```

The subparser mechanism is similar to

```
parser.add_argument('cmd', choices=['command1','command2']
```

The 'command1' string tells it - parser the reset of the strings using the '-a -b ...' group of arguments.  It has to know which group you expect it to use.

Short of using the bug/issue patch that I worked on a while back, you need to do your own 'mutually-exclusive' testing after parsing.  As long as you use the default default `None`, it is is easy to test whether an argument has been used or now (`args.AA is not None`).

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30337890/901925 is a recent example of doing post-parsing testing.

Comment: the code must be able to work without specifing any argument, the line where you used `-AA` and `-BB` is not `ok` and the code have to terminate in that case too

Comment: My focus is on what your code does.  You could give `parser_b` a mutually exclusive group..  But with subparsers you can't get way with 0 arguments.  If you don't like the subparser option, then doing your own post-parsing testing is the way to go.  There are lots of SO about doing that.

Comment: i went with solution you have linked and just decided to check arguments with an condition which i added into my thread, works for my case